# How to get a UITableViewCell's subtitle show how many times that specific cell was tapped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a uitableview that displays the values of an array. I would like to know if there is a way to update the subtitle of its table cells, based on how many times each cell was tapped.

Thank you!

Comment: I have successfully managed to update all subtitles when a cell is tapped, using - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, however I m a bit confused when it comes to many different values. I am trying to solve this issue using a dictionary, having stored the values for the array as keys and maybe the count of taps for each key as its corresponding value, but no luck so far. I also need to point out that I am new to objective-c and iOS dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to use a `NSMutableArray` so you can change its contents after instantiation. Here's a basic over view of what I just tried to achieve your intended results:

In your interface

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tapCountArray;
```

In your implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tapCountArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    int numberOfRows = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i ++) {
        [self.tapCountArray addObject:@(0)];
    }
}
```

Then the important part!

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tapCountArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *text = [self.tapCountArray[indexPath.row] stringValue];
    [cell.textLabel setText:text];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tapCountArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@([self.tapCountArray[indexPath.row] intValue] + 1)];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

When each cell is tapped the number in its `detailTextLabel` will be incremented up by one.

Comment: Works like a charm! However there is something I didnt expect to happen. Now my cells when are tapped they lose their animation effect(blue selection fades to white). Can this be caused by calling reloadData? Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1644365 Sorry about that, I made an edit to my post that should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create a new array or set, that could lead to problems if the two arrays get out of sync with each other.  The way to do it, as you suggested in your comment, is to use dictionaries. The way you said you were doing that is probably not the way, however.  You want an array of dictionaries where the values for one key would be whatever your main data is and the value for the other key would be the number of taps. For example, lets call the two keys main and sub, and your main data is a set of names.  The array of dictionaries would look like this: ({main:@"Tom",sub:1}, {main:@"Dick", sub:0}, {main:@"Harry",sub:2}, .....). In the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath method you would provide the data to the cells like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"main"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sub"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set up another array of the same length as the one you have now. Then when your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is triggered, increment your `indexPath.row` entry of the new array and refresh that cell. If you don't expect to shuffle the table, you don't need a dictionary.

Comment: Great! I ll give it a try and let you know. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the object into an NSCountedSet, and on your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you would take the model object for the cell and verify the number of times it has been inserted into the NSCountedSet instance.

Take a look at the NSCountedSet documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you I ve been looking to that too. I ll try it!